# get id from radio input by clicking a link (siblings?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so i have a list of addresses each with edit links and i want to grab the ID of the input within the list item

```
<li class="last">
    <div class="checkout-select-address"><input type="radio" name="checkout_selected_address" id="checkout_selected_address_3" value="" /></div>
    <div class="checkout-select-address-details">
    <p><label for="checkout_selected_address_3">(Mothers)</label> <a href="#" title="Edit Address" class="edit-link right">Edit Address</a></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="checkout_selected_address_3_name" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="checkout_selected_address_3_title" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="checkout_selected_address_3_first_name" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="checkout_selected_address_3_last_name" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="checkout_selected_address_3_address_line_1" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="checkout_selected_address_3_address_line_2" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="checkout_selected_address_3_address_line_3" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="checkout_selected_address_3_town_city" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="checkout_selected_address_3_county" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="checkout_selected_address_3_postcode" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="checkout_selected_address_3_country" value="" />
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

so clicking on the link with class "edit-link" it will get the ID for the radio input within the li

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$(".edit-link").click(function(){
   alert($(this).closest("li").find("input[type=radio]").attr("id"));
});
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ZABBS/

Comment: I get undefined with that example, plus there will be more than 1 address, so need to gran the unique radio id by clicking the link within the current LI

Comment: I just worked it out using: alert($(this).closest("li").find("input[name=checkout_selected_address]").attr("id"));

Comment: @mgraph _Attribute values in selector expressions must follow the rules for W3C CSS selectors, in general that means anything other than a simple identifier should be surrounded by quotation marks_ [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)